# Problem reading AttachedProperty in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, attached-properties

This is my attached property:

```
public class MyButtonThing
{
    public static string GetText2(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(Text2Property);
    }
    public static void SetText2(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(Text2Property, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text2Property =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text2", 
        typeof(string), typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button));
}
```

This is my ControlTemplate:

**EDIT** this will work fine:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
                     x:Key="MyButtonTemplate">
        <Border>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                           DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                          AncestorType=Button},
                          Path=(local:MyButtonThing.Text2)}"  />
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}" 
        local:MyButtonThing.Text2="Where's Waldo"
        >Hello World</Button>
```

My problem? Text2 renders properly in the Desginer, not at runtime.

Comment: In silverlight, binding to custom attached property is a problem however I have read somewhere that you can try putting entire name of attached property in round brackets and see if it works or not

Comment: I wish that worked; tried `(local:MyButtonThing).Text2` but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the value on the button, and it is attached, hence:

```xml
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},
         Path=(local:MyButtonThing.Text2)}
```

Comment: Well, that's perfect. But, could you explain why it is so obvious? There's clearly something I do not understand. Why doesn't Self work?

Comment: @JerryNixon: Self points towards the TextBlock, the propety you want to bind to is not set on that TextBlock but the Button which contains the TextBlock. Besides that you need the parentheses around the property to indicate that you bind to an attached property (obviously this is an attached property).

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the `DataContext` of `TextBox`, which doesn't have a `Text2` property

Use this instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                   Path=local:MyButtonThing.Text2}" />
```

It sets the TextBox's `DataContext` to the TextBox Control, not the TextBox's DataContext

Comment: I updated my code sample to use your syntax, but still it is not reading the value of the attached property.